# Open file in visual studio document window on first project load when project is created with custom made project template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I've made a custom project template and when I create a new project in Visual Studio using this template I want to open a file(which belongs to the template) into the Visual Studio's *document window*(code editor window/whatever...) right after the project is loaded.

If, for example, I create a **C# - .NET Framework - Console Application** the file *Program.cs* is opened after the project is fully created and loaded into Visual Studio.
When I use my custom template, no file is opened and the *document window* is empty.
I would like to achieve the same behavior as it happens for the built-in templates and have a file be opened when the project is loaded

I suspect I would have to edit the *.vstemplate* file and add some specific tag that would instruct Visual Studio to do that, but I can't find anything useful in the [microsoft documentation relating vstemplate element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vstemplate-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2019).

Comment: `OpenInEditor="true"`, find the example in (say) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication\csConsoleApplication.vstemplate

Comment: Yep, it works now. Don't know how didn't I thought of checking that file by now. Thanks!
You could rewrite the comment as answer so I can accept it.